# Handling multiple view controllers in my Ui

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, categories

i am planning to use multiple view controllers in my Ui for particular function.
example  i have a buttons named as Animals,Vehicles,instruments.each of them representing the categories.

in my DB i have many entries or subcategories for the 3 categories.

Example:Vehicles have 3 sub categories named as 3 wheeler,2 wheeler,4 wheeler.

in the above sub category 4 wheeler,  i have another subcategories named as Bus,Car,Van etc.

the sub categories are not fixed . user can save any number of subcategories under each category.

Help me please...

now the ui look like 3 buttons named as Animals,Vehicles,instruments(main categories).

when i click onVehicles button ,it will navigate a new window and will display the corresponding subcategories(3 wheeler,2 wheeler,4 wheeler).

when i click on 4 wheeler ,it will navigate a new window and will display the corresponding subcategories(Bus,Car,Van).the process will continue until when a category does not have any sub categories.

also the same process for another main categories(Animals,instruments) according to the DB values/maching sub categories.

i am confused with the Ui design.can any one tell me how can i do this.is need to use separate views for each sub category.then how can i handle the views.

there is a common section in ui to add and update the added categories in bottom of the screen.how can i change /navigate the views without affecting the section.can any one provide me a good way to do it. i like to do it in a single view.but look like we are navigating to another view when selecting a category.

Comment: You have been warned to stop trying to circumvent your suspension. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Table View Controller and seed it with your data from .plists or another data source.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

This sounds like it fits your case best.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an idea on how to use the `NavigationController`, `TableViewController` and `TabBarController`. Just watch  [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw) , and you will be able to understand the basics !!